# Parametrize endpoints in FastApi

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a collecton of GET endpoints named `/endpoint1/{id}`, `/endpoint2/{id}` that do essentially the same thing. See the below toy example. I'm trying to factor out the redundent `get1` and `get2` into a `get`. The problem is that the swagger docs for `endpoint3/{id}` has the documentation from the docstring of the partial function. See

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

```
from functools import partial

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/endpoint1/{id}")
def get1(id: str) -> str:
    return "endpoint1" + id


@app.get("/endpoint2/{id}")
def get2(id: str) -> str:
    return "endpoint2" + id


def get(endpoint: str, id: str) -> str:
    return endpoint + id


app.get("/endpoint3/{id}")(partial(get, endpoint="endpoint3"))
```

It's not an option for me to have a single GET endpoint with two arguments `endpoint` and `id`. What is the proper way to refactor this code and to rapidly create this family of GET endpoints? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this suits my purposes:

```
from typing import Callable

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/endpoint1/{id}")
def get1(id: str) -> str:
    return "endpoint1" + id


@app.get("/endpoint2/{id}")
def get2(id: str) -> str:
    return "endpoint2" + id


def get_factory(endpoint: str) -> Callable[[str], str]:
    def get(id: str) -> str:
        return endpoint + id

    return get


app.get("/endpoint3/{id}")(get_factory("endpoint3"))
```